# Hibernate LOG: A soft-locked cache entry was expired by the underlying cache

Tags: hibernate, caching, hazelcast, second-level-cache, query-cache

I think i have problem with Cache eviction, query cache and second-level-cache.

I am using Hazelcast in my spring boot project. I have @Cache and @Cachable on entity Document and both second level and query cache are enabled. But also on my findByUuid i have query hint which enables query cache (org.hibernate.cache = true).

My problem is that in one transcation session Document object is created and "persisted" (commit is not maded), then one method does findByUuid and it gets Document. But after few lines findByUuid is also tried and it gets null. My log have messages that Cache is created, then i get message :

**A soft-locked cache entry was expired by the underlying cache. If this happens regularly you should consider increasing the cache timeouts and/or capacity limits**

and at the end i get Cache cleared message.